# Unable to use Scrollbar when using a Tablet

Tags: html, css

I was experiencing issues for my website when I'm using tablets because the scrollbar is not scrolling.

I believe it is because for tablets I am unable to trigger the scroll event.

HTML and CSS provided below!

```css
.scroll-pane {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 99%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.scroll-content {
  width: 1975px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.scroll-content-item {
  width: 59px;
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap {
  clear: left;
  padding: 0 4px 0 2px;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 0;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle {
  top: .2em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon {
  margin: -8px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  background-image: none;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: default;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-pane" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="scroll-bar-wrap">
    <div class="scroll-bar ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-                                                     widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 99%;">
      <div class="ui-handle-helper-parent"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 81%;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is not your friend here.

Comment: Yes but I doubt it's the cause of this issue...